# Insert multiple values in one column of mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to insert multiple values with one html input,
HTML input will have text with seperated by semicolon, will use explode function to create array and then want to pass this array to mysql

I have created below code,

```
if($this->input->post('create_category'))
    {
        $category_chunk = $this->input->post('category_name');
        $category_list = explode(";", $category_chunk);

        $category_array = array(
                    'category_name' =>$category_list );

        $result = $this->model_admin->create_expense_category($category_array);}
```

When i click Create category, it throw error " Message: Array to string conversion" and "INSERT INTO `ec_ex_category` (`category_name`) VALUES (Array)"

I know this is created due to 'category_name' =>$category_list,

I dont know how to pass array in 'category_name' column,
I am using codeigniter.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: Show us your model please.

Comment: function create_expense_category($category_array)
 {
  $this->db->insert('ec_ex_category',$category_array);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send an array within an array to your model. To insert multiple lines in one line you need to use insert_batch which require an array of arrays to work :

Controller :

```
$category_list = explode(";", $category_chunk);

$category_array = array();
foreach($category_list as $c)
{
    $category_array[] = array('category_name' =>$c)
}
```

Then in your model :

```
$this->db->insert_batch('ec_ex_category',$category_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

$category_list is array so you have to get category_name from it first and then to insert it.

Example:

$category_name = $category_list[0] // Whatever index is name in array

then insert $category_name.

Comment: Hi, Thank it working partially, i tried to add hi;test;hello, but it added only hi because of first index, how to add all?

Comment: What is not working ? Can you paste $category_list array here ?

Comment: I added test;hi;hello, exploded array $category_list shows like ---- Array ( [0] => test [1] => hi [2] => hello ),  How can i add all 3 in table?

Comment: You can add that with the help of loop:

$category_list = explode(";", $category_chunk);

for ($i=0;$i<count($category_list);$i++)
{
   $this->db->insert('table_name',$category_list[$i]);
}

Also,you can use codeIgniter insert_batch method to insert array